# Update position of UIImageView (a Stone 'object') with Animations not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to code the movement of swiping a 'stone' image around a 5x5 grid.
In short, if one of my stones starts at col 3, row 1, and I swipe down, it should end up in col 3, row 4 (Based on an NSInteger array of board[5][5]).
I have an Outlet View instance variable in @implementation { }, as such:

```
    IBOutlet UIView* _one;
```

Here's everything that happens when I swipe down on view '_one'

```
    - (void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
         NSLog(@"Swipe Down");
         UIView *view = recognizer.view;
         if (view == _one) {
             _currentCol = stoneOneColumn;
             _currentRow = stoneOneRow;
             _state = (BoardCellState)BoardCellStateStoneOne;
             NSLog(@"Got it 3");
         } else if (view == _two) { // code for '_two' }
         [self move:CGPointMake(0, 1) withView:view];
    }

    - (void)move:(CGPoint)direction withView:(UIView*)stoneView {
         NSLog(@"Got it 5");
         CGFloat oldCol = _currentCol;
         CGFloat oldRow = _currentRow;
         while ([self indexValid:_currentCol y:_currentRow]) {
             NSLog(@"Got it 5.5");
             CGFloat newCol = _currentCol + direction.x;
             CGFloat newRow = _currentRow + direction.y;
             if ([self indexValid:newCol y:newRow]) {
                 NSLog(@"Got it 5.75");
                 _currentCol = newCol;
                 _currentRow = newRow;
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Got it close to 6");
                 _currentCol = newCol;
                 _currentRow = newRow;
                 break;
             }
         }
         NSLog(@"Got it 6");
         [_board setCellState:BoardCellStateEmpty forColumn:oldCol
                                                     andRow:oldRow];
         [_board setCellState:_state forColumn:_currentCol 
                                        andRow:_currentRow];
         NSLog(@"Got it 7");
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                               delay:1.0
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                          animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = stoneView.frame;
                             rect.origin.x = 
                                 _frame.origin.x + (_currentCol*61.5);
                             rect.origin.y =
                                 _frame.origin.y + (_currentRow*61.5);
                          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Done finally");
                          }];
    }

    - (BOOL)indexValid:(NSInteger)x y:(NSInteger)y {
        NSLog(@"Got it 8");
        BOOL indexValid = TRUE;
        if ((x < 0) || (x > 4) || (y < 0) || (y > 4)) {
            NSLog(@"Got it 10");
            indexValid = FALSE;
            return indexValid;
        } else
            return indexValid;
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.358 Twinstones[8672:907] Swipe Down
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.363 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 3
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.365 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.367 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.368 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.370 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.5
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.372 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8 
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.374 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.375 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.75
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.377 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.379 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.380 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.5
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.382 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.384 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.385 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.75
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.387 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.389 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.392 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.5
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.393 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.395 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.397 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.75
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.398 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.400 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.402 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 5.5
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.403 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 8
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.405 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 9
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.407 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 10
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.409 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it close to 6
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.411 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 6
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.412 Twinstones[8672:907] Got it 7
    2016-04-04 01:52:22.416 Twinstones[8672:907] Done finally
```

Here are some comments on what's going on:

```
    1. BoardCellState is an enum (...StoneOne or ...StoneTwo) signifies the
       state of the stone (is the view I'm animating one or two).
    2. The while loop runs through the numerical positions, using the 
       indexValid method to break it when either col or row positions exceed
       the _board[5][5] 'boundary'.
    3. There are setter and getter methods in another file for stone positions.
       I set the Empty state to the old column and row, and set the current
       state to the new column and row.
    4. THEN I perform the animation! But the problem is, the stone on my 
       iPhone (when I test it, that is) doesn't move at all, even though
       the output goes through this entire process.  That's where I'm stuck.
```

I can't tell what the issue is.  Is it the code inside the 'animations:' block?
Do I need to change my return value for the 'move: withView:' method?
Does the [UIView ...] of the animation method understand that what I want to animate is the 'stoneView' that I successfully passed throughout the process?

thanks for taking a look at this
-Anthony

Comment: Sorry but reading whole question still not getting me what is the problem.

Comment: So ignore all the code but the 'animations:' block in the animation method.  I'm trying to update the position of my stone image.  So if I swipe, I want that stone to move and update its positions.  Everything works in terms of position storage, but the animation is not working.  My stone is not moving, it's just staying put in its original spot.

Comment: include error log will helps me to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to reassign `rect` to `stoneView.frame`

```
animations:^{
CGRect rect = stoneView.frame;
rect.origin.x = 
_frame.origin.x + (_currentCol*61.5);
rect.origin.y =
_frame.origin.y + (_currentRow*61.5);
```

> stoneView.frame = rect;

```
}
```

Comment: Great response, completely forgot to reassign the CGRect, thanks!